# ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, respond-to

In my rails app I have a ajax request to the server, to store some data. This used to work without any problem, but now I get an error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/reservations_controller.rb:45:in `create'
```

As following is the controller and my javascript file where I declare the datatype do be JSON

```
class ReservationController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :json

  def create
    ...
    respond_to do |format|
      if @reservation.save
        format.html do
          redirect_to '/'
        end
        format.json { render json: @reservation.to_json }
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end # respond_to
  end # create 
end # ReservationController
```

function.js

```
$.ajax({
        url: url_link,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataToSend
      })
```

The complete error log is:

```
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 45ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb:45:in `create'

Rendered /Users/tiagovieira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.5ms)
Rendered /Users/tiagovieira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered /Users/tiagovieira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered /Users/tiagovieira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (9.6ms)
```

Comment: Can you share the complete server log when you get this error?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Update the `create` action as below:

```
def create
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    if @reservation.save
      format.html do
        redirect_to '/'
      end
      format.json { render json: @reservation.to_json }
    else
      format.html { render 'new'} ## Specify the format in which you are rendering "new" page
      format.json { render json: @reservation.errors } ## You might want to specify a json format as well
    end
  end
end
```

You are using `respond_to` method but anot specifying the **format** in which a `new` page is rendered. Hence, the error `ActionController::UnknownFormat` .

Comment: exactly, apparently he's not saving on the database (the if @reservation.save returns false) but I no longer get the error

Comment: Yup..you would get the error only when `@reservation.save` fails as in that case `else` part is executed where the format is missing.

Comment: You DO NOT need to specify format.html or format.json UNLESS you invoke render within a respond_to block!

Answer (score 33):

You can also modify your config/routes.rb file like:

```
 get 'ajax/:action', to: 'ajax#:action', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

Which will default the format to json.
It is working fine for me in Rails 4.

Or if you want to go even further and you are using namespaces, you can cut down the duplicates:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
   #your controller routes here ...
end
```

with the above everything under `/api` will be formatted as json by default.

Answer (score 7):

There is another scenario where this issue reproduces (as in my case). When THE CLIENT REQUEST doesn't contain the right extension on the url, the controller can't identify the desired result format.

For example: the controller is set to `respond_to :json` (as a single option, without a HTML response)- while the client call is set to `/reservations` instead of `/reservations.json`.

Bottom line, change the client call to `/reservations.json`.

Answer (score 4):

This problem happened with me and sovled by just add

```
 respond_to :html, :json
```

to ApplicationController file

You can Check Devise issues on Github: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2667

Comment: That's not a method the ApplicationController understands.

Comment: @Adamantish do you mean "respond_to" ? you can check github issues link attached.

Comment: Indeed. Perhaps there's some reason to do with rails 5 that it wasn't a recognised method in that context for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well I fond this post because I got a similar error.
So I added the top line like in your controller
respond_to :html, :json

then I got a different error(see below)

The controller-level `respond_to' feature has been extracted to the`responders` gem. Add it to your Gemfile to continue using this feature: gem 'responders', '~> 2.0' Consult the Rails upgrade guide for details.
But that had nothing to do with it.

Comment: It was the missing script tags in my layout.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to render an XML response - I had to change my template name from index.html.erb to index.xml.erb and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

mine was fixed because i didnt have  / / in the scope,
i had this (getting error for json):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope '(:base_url)', base_url: #{ENV.fetch('BASE_URL').to_s} do
    ...
  end
end
```

instead of this (fixed):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope '(:base_url)', base_url: /#{ENV.fetch('BASE_URL').to_s}/ do
    ...
  end
end
```