# Rack-CORS error on Redirection

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, redirect

I am experiencing a problem with cross-origin requests being disallowed with rack-cors 0.2.9 on Rails 4.1.0 as my API. I'm using Angularjs as a front end to add a record to this Rails application. Chrome was showing this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/passages. The request
was redirected to 'http://localhost:3000/passages/67', which is
disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

I think I figured out why this is occurring. Here is my "create" action in the controller:

```
def create
    @passage = Passage.new(passage_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @passage.save
        format.html { redirect_to @passage, notice: 'Passage was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @passage }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @passage.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Note that once the passage is saved, I get redirected to the "show" action of the specific passage record created. Apparently, it is this redirection that is triggering the XHR error.

My question is how to configure the response in my Rails controller so that this error is avoided. If I don't redirect, what should I be doing?

Thx

UPDATE: I failed to mention that the new record does indeed get created in spite of the error.

UPDATE: In reading the Rails 4 documentation I learned that it is possible to simply respond with headers to the browser. See [the rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses)

However, now I am getting a `POST http://localhost:3000/passages 406 (Not Acceptable)` error in the console. Researching this status code seems to indicate that my rails application is not returning an acceptable response to my application. I'm struggling to determine what response would be acceptable. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out after reading an answer from this other [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944769/964018) post.

Here is my updated controller code. Note the previous code commented out:

```
def create
@passage = Passage.new(passage_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @passage.save
    format.html do
      head 200, content_type: "text/plain"
    end
    format.json { render json: @passage.to_json }

    # format.html { redirect_to @passage, notice: 'Passage was successfully created.' }
    # format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @passage }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @passage.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```