# "ActionController::UnknownFormat" as a result of using AJAX with format.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have models: idea,item,product.
I'm trying to add Products to Ideas through Items in a view of Idea's editing.
My edit.html.erb - Idea

```
<div id="items">
  <%= render @idea.items %>
</div>

<div class="products">
  <% @products.each do |p| %>
    <%= p.title %><%= button_to '+', items_path(product_id: p.id, idea_id: @idea.id), remote: true %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My items controller:

```
def create
    product = Product.friendly.find(params[:product_id])
    @item = @idea.add_product(product.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.js 
      end
    end
  end
```

idea.rb

```
 def add_product(product_id)
         item = items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
         if item
         else
            item = items.build(product_id: product_id)
         end
         item
    end
```

My "create.js.erb"

```
$('#items').html("<%= escape_javascript render(@idea.items) %>");
```

When I put "format.html {redirect_to :back}" in def create (items_controller) everything goes OK, but without AJAX=(

Logs

> Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 91ms
>
> ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
>   app/controllers/items_controller.rb:33:in `create'

Help me, guys. I have googled the whole internet

Comment: it's likely you need to write the else, or remove if , see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944769/1197775

Comment: Try to change `respond_to ... format.js` with `render "create.js.erb"`. Also handle situation when item is not saved

Comment: Thank you for advices, but ... I tried to put "else" statement in my def create, but i didn't hepl me, cause statement of saving item was performing. Removing "if" also didn't give me anything.

Comment: Pavel, render of "create.js.erb" didn't help me. When i pushed to the button, rails brought me to the page with this code: $('#items').html("\n<li>MDC-4220C<form action=\"/items/219\" class=\"button_to\" data-remote=\"true\" method=type=\"submit\" value=\"X\" /><input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"k9LNh3DAV/bBxoMjkzHa6G0Qmlv5uBfLe9l80MAfwJg=\" /><\/div><\/form><\/li>\n<li>KIC-301<form action=\"/items/220\" class=\"button_to\" data-remote=\"true\" method=\"post\"><div><input name=\"_method\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"delete\" /><input type=\"submit\"  AND SO ON(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those who are still googling... It helped me to specify defaults: => {format: 'js'} for ajax actions in routes.rb.

```
post 'myaction' => 'mycontroller#myaction', defaults: { format: 'js' }
```

Comment: @LuigiAlver for CrossOrigin error following an ajax call see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310187/rails-invalidcrossoriginrequest