# Rails InvalidCrossOriginRequest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, request

I have a `remote: true` link on a page in my Rails app which calls a `.js` version of the same page and then runs a script to update the pages content in place.

It was working fine but since yesterday I now get `Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.` everytime I click one of those links.

Any ideas on how I can stop this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Add this to the controller that is rendering your page fragment

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery except: :index
```

Where `index` is the name of the action you wanna skip this protection

---

### Cross-Origin Policy

The error you were getting is because of what is called Cross-Origin policy. It's a standard present in every browser that don't allow a page to run scripts from other domains. The way to go around this is adding a header to the http request allowing your content to be run in other domains.

Wikipedia has an explanation for this:

> The second technique for relaxing the same-origin policy is
> standardized under the name Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. This
> standard extends HTTP with a new Origin request header and a new
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. It allows servers to use
> a header to explicitly list origins that may request a file or to use
> a wildcard and allow a file to be requested by any site. Browsers such
> as Firefox 3.5, Safari 4 and Internet Explorer 10 use this header to
> allow the cross-origin HTTP requests with XMLHttpRequest that would
> otherwise have been forbidden by the same-origin policy.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Ok, So this work but may you please explain why my application was doing that in the first place and what this is doing that solves the problem?

Comment: I've added the explanation. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. What's confusing me is this is all on the same domain?

Comment: You could be mixing resources in http and https protocols

Comment: This isn't safe when using SJR: https://github.com/jcoglan/unsafe_sjr. It allows any site to get whatever data you're injecting into the DOM with index.js.erb

Comment: The reason it fails on the same domain is Rails' Cross-Origin check does not actually check the origin. (1) it is a GET request, and (2) it is not an XHR request. Your use case satisfies both of these, so the error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than skipping all forgery protection / authenticity token validation, you can just skip the "cross origin" check.

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
    skip_after_action :verify_same_origin_request
```

The reason you need to skip this is because Rails' `verify_same_origin_request` does not actually check the origin. Instead it checks (1) it is a GET request, and (2) it is not an XHR request. Your use case satisfies both of these, so an error is raised.