# ActionController::UnknownFormat respond_to do |format|

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My product_controller

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController
    
    def index
        @product = Product.all 
        @categories = Category.all
    end
    
    def from_category
        @product = Product.joins(:category).where(category: { id: params[:cat_id] })
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end
end
```

My form_category.js.erb

```
$("#products_grid").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'product/products_list', locals: { product: @selected } ) %>");
```

I want to filter products by categories and found this way, but I get an error on this part

[image]

Comment: if you called product/from_category directly from the browser, that's an HTML call. add a format.html block

Comment: You need to specify the format is "js" if that is what you want to use [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339130/how-do-i-render-a-partial-of-a-different-format-in-rails). You have not posted how you are actually trying to access this controller method so it is difficult to help here.

Comment: I replaced it
respond_to do |format|
           format.js
       end
on this
render formats: [ :html ]

and now i have this error

Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to allow cross-origin JavaScript embedding.

Comment: and when i insert it
protect_from_forgery except: :index
or this
skip_after_action :verify_same_origin_request

from this source

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310187/rails-invalidcrossoriginrequest

my localhost shows this


$("#products_grid").html("    <div class=\"product_box\">\n      <a href=\"/products\">Mirror&#39;s Edge<\/a>\n    <\/div>\n    <div class=\"product_box\">\n      <a href=\"/products\">Pokémon SoulSilver<\/a>\n    <\/div>\n    <div class=\"product_box\">\n      <a href=\"/products\">Pokémon .......

but I have such a problem that I attached above

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to learn it all, but I don't understand everything, help me, please

Comment: can you post the request from rails server logs?

Comment: Processing by ProductController#from_category as HTML
  Parameters: {"cat_id"=>"1"}
  Rendering product/from_category.js.erb
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
  ↳ app/views/product/_products_list.html.erb:1
  Rendered product/_products_list.html.erb (Duration: 3.1ms | Allocations: 1805)
  Rendered product/from_category.js.erb (Duration: 3.7ms | Allocations: 2146)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 2576)