# Rails/AJAX: Partial not displaying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

**Background** (changed after correspondance with @TomLord):

I am building a simple site with only a index page and no subpages. The index page has a "search" field that takes input (`id`) and sends a GET request to a RESTful API running in the background. The response from the API is JSON `{"market price": "4306057.0", "retail price": "4995000.0"}`.

I want to display this result on the index page, together with the search field. However, **when I press the button the result is not displayed anywhere**.

---

**Code**:

`index.html.erb`

```
<section id="search">
  <div class="container">
    <%= form_tag({controller: "model_request", action: "result"}, method: "get", remote: true) do %>
      <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for") %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:q, "913384637") %>
      <%= submit_tag("Get the price!") %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="display_result">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</section>
```

And the `modelrequest_controller.rb` looks like this:

```
class ModelrequestController < ApplicationController

  def result
    id = params['q'].capitalize
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      method:  :get,
      url:     "http://0.0.0.0:80/?id=#{id}")
    @result = JSON.parse response

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render layout: false}
    end
  end

  end
```

My `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'index#index'

  match "/modelrequest", to: "modelrequest#result", via: 'get'

end
```

The javascript for results looks like this:

`result.js.erb`

```
$("#display_result").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'modelrequest/result', locals: { result: @result } ) %>");
```

And the simple `_result.html.erb` for displaying the partial is

```
<div id="display_result">
  <%= @result %>
</div>
```

---

**Output**:

```
Started GET "/model_request?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=913384637&commit=Get%20the%20price!" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-19 20:55:33 +0100
Processing by ModelRequestController#result as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>"913384637", "commit"=>"Get the price!"}
  Rendering model_request/result.js.erb
  Rendered model_request/_result.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered model_request/result.js.erb (6.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 383ms (Views: 11.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: You can define a `show.js.erb` (or `show.js.haml`), to **replace the contents of a container** (probably a `div`) with the search results. Something along the lines of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35900332/1954610

Comment: Additionally, note the `remote: true` in the form. You want this to be an AJAX request, not a full page reload.

Comment: Hi @TomLord, thanks for the input. I've edited my post and updated the code.

Comment: The idea is that you pace a "results `div`" on the index page. Let's call that `.results`. Then in the `show.js.haml`, you update the contents of this container. So something like: `$(".results").html("#{escape_javascript(......`. You can call this container whatever you like (`#main`?), but it needs to be present on that page.

Comment: Also, in your case, it's the **form** that needs to send data remotely; there's no need for a `link_to` here. For example, see http://www.korenlc.com/remote-true-in-rails-forms/. We're not changing the way that your form works; we're only changing what gets rendered at the end. Originally, you were rendering a new page; now, we're replacing the contents of a `div`, on the same page.

Comment: Dear @TomLord, thanks again! The `GET` method to the API now works, the index page is able to load and pressing the button actually results in a request to the API which responds correctly. Hurray! However, I am still not able to make the result appear correctly. It seems that it is looking for a template, despite `{render layout: false}` in the controller. I have changed the code in my question to a updated version.

Comment: Yes, it's looking for a template -- that's correct. You've named the controller `ModelrequestController`, which means it's looking for `app/views/modelrequest/result.js.erb`. However, you've named the file `app/views/model_requests/result.js.erb`. Either rename the folder, or rename the controller to `ModelRequestsController`.

Comment: This is what the error message is telling you :)

Comment: Great. Stupid mistake. Now everything seems to work, just need to figure out how to display the result in index.html.haml. If you write your comments up as an answer (just partially) I will be happy to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a "normal" rails site, a search form works as follows -

You define a form in the view. This will, by default, `POST` data to an endpoint - but you can also do this via a `GET` request. In your case, you originally chose:

```
form_tag("/search", method: "get")
```

This will send the form data to `GET /search`, synchronously, and therefore perform a full page reload.

This is a perfectly valid thing to do. However, you wanted to *remain on the index page* - therefore the request needs to be asynchronous:

```
form_tag("/search", method: "get", remote: true)
```

...But now, that endpoint needs to do something different. Instead of rendering a new page, it needs to *partially update the current page*.

The standard approach for this in a rails application is to do something along the lines of:

```
# In the controller action, e.g. SearchController
def show
  @results = # ...

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render layout: false}
  end
end

# In the view, e.g. `search/show.js.erb`
$("#display_result").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'results', locals: { results: @results } ) %>");

# In an HTML partial, e.g. `search/_results.html.erb`
<% results.each do %>
  ...
```

The key idea is that on your main page (`index.html.erb`?), you must have a **container** to display the results. Then, rather than rendering a new page, you are merely rendering an HTML update inside that container.

---

This is, of course, not the only way of doing it. Modern websites will often instead fetch JSON data for a search result and then determine how to display that via JavaScript.

However, the above approach is the most "minimal" change from your current design - without needing to add additional design patterns, you can leave most of your existing `haml`/`erb` templates as-is, and just add a little code to render the results as a partial.

Comment: Hi Tom! I've accepted your answer. I think I understand the overall structure, and I have made it work if I don't use the `respond_to do |format| ...` but simply call `@result` in with a `link_from(...` so the result pops up in a message when I click the link. However, rendering the partial still does not work, even though I am defining a container to display the result (see code above). The only difference I can see is `_results.html.erb` where mine is simply `<div id="display_result"> <%= @result %> </div>`. My suspicion is that my container is defined wrong in `index.html.erb`.

Comment: Just spent half an hour trying to figure out why my partial stopped working and it was this: 
"$("#display_result").html("...
I deleted or changed the ID of the container rendering the js. *smacks forehead* Cheers!