# AJAX respond_to is not wroking

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to use javascript with AJAX in Rails, but is not working.

The `login.hmtl.erb` file:

```
<%= form_for :web_app, :html => { :id => 'login_form' } , :url => {:action => 'authentication'}, :remote => true  do |f| %>
```

The `web_app_controller.rb` action:

```
  def authentication
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

The `authentication.js.erb` file

`console.log("hi");`

I get this error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

I have done this before and worked fine, but don't know why I can't make it work. I do not know what I'm missing.

**Update**

log:

> Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-21 03:05:14 -0300
>   Processing by WebAppController#login as HTML   Rendering
>   web_app/login.html.erb within layouts/application   Rendered
>   web_app/login.html.erb within layouts/application (15.1ms) Completed
>   200 OK in 77ms (Views: 73.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-21 03:05:43 -0300
>   Processing by WebAppController#authentication as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"sFdGP449Z0Av5eMUPFYOAB/zvTAFViOoDcjFIfXWwu8/oj0iCpnN6fznk6f5AhQU7LSub+cvW2MWtMTD7SwgWA==",
>   "web_app"=>{"code"=>"AQBIzFfceuIFFFsepBU2qzZfbY4nefzDLJFHQk8ZQ0rfp8mdBQHW4PLtWA_558Iro6HJiAKmN7_WI4aioLB96g42K-LPEHjbHJXnKUT_-KOxTHPsgfWXjx0m6yvuIF64Fd3KQTIgvX7AU3y4ibgnQVJFme6omcNl6sBCbxerDav6T3t6dEGYin8f8I0ewbAEvcLpu2u08ZtNH6RbPEo93rZVmAoc9Zu4TsDTSQ_R0-CQah72ZBaIr9bU3MesjuiXqRNj8dxWIrUnUlfE0rCo5gBK",
>   "csrf"=>"abcd"}} Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 3ms (ActiveRecord:
>   0.0ms)
>
> ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionController::UnknownFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943892/actioncontrollerunknownformat)

Comment: Could you please post your request log?

Comment: @SSR posted in update.

Comment: @exsnake WebAppController#authentication as HTML This line from the log says that you request is HTML. It should be JS. Could you please inspect your login form to confirm that is remote true assign to form or not.

Comment: @SSR yes, is true :/

Answer (score 0):

In your web_app_controller.rb

Add this line after controller class declaration.

```
respond_to :js, only: [:authentication]
```

Remove respond_to block from authentication method. Then resubmit request. Check browser console to see log.

Comment: That gives me an error. `
undefined method `respond_to' for WebAppController:Class Did you mean? respond_to?`

Comment: @exsnake where did you put this line?